# Jquery callbacks with several ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have several functions where I'm filling a dropdown based on a list from an ajax call :

```
function getMissions(defaultId) {
    $.getJSON("Defaults/GetMissions", function (result) {
        var dropDownToFill = $('#change-mission');
        fillUpdateDropDown(dropDownToFill, result);
    });
}
function getSectors(defaultId) {
    $.getJSON("Defaults/GetSectors", function (result) {
        var dropDownToFill = $('#change-sector');
        fillUpdateDropDown(dropDownToFill, result);
    });
}
```

Now, after dropdown have been filled, I want to select a specific item, but to get this item, I need an other ajax like :

```
function getDefaultDetails(defaultId) {
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Defaults/GetDefault",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { defaultId: defaultId },
        success: function (response) {
            //code here to select the items from the response
        },
    });
}
```

and the main function would basically be :

```
function main(defaultId){
    getMissions(defaultId);
    getSectors(defaultId);
    getDefaultDetails(defaultId);
}
```

The trouble is that the `success` callback of `getDefaultDetails` is reached before `fillUpdateDropDown` has been finished (dropdowns could have a lot of items).

I'm trying to understand the callbacks but in my case i cannot achieve my problem. I have tried something like :

```
 $.when(getMissions(defaultId), getSectors(defaultId)).done(getDefaultDetails(defaultId));
```

but without success.

How to perform that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) expects [*thenable*](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Thenable) objects (Promise, Deferred, Thenable) like the return value of `$.getJSON()`.

You also have to wrap the call for `getDefaultDetails()` in `.done()` in an anonymous function, otherwise you're executing the function and only use its return value (`undefined`) for `.done()`

```
function getMissions(defaultId) {
    return $.getJSON("Defaults/GetMissions", function (result) {
        var dropDownToFill = $('#change-mission');
        fillUpdateDropDown(dropDownToFill, result);
    });
}

function getSectors(defaultId) {
    return $.getJSON("Defaults/GetSectors", function (result) {
        var dropDownToFill = $('#change-sector');
        fillUpdateDropDown(dropDownToFill, result);
    });
}

function getDefaultDetails() { /* ... */ }

$.when(getMissions(defaultId), getSectors(defaultId))
 .done(function() { getDefaultDetails(defaultId) });
```